# EC2 disk usage from web console

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is it possible to use the EC2 web console to view the disk usage of a volume attached to a running EC2 instance?

I know I can ssh into the instance and use commands such as `$ df -h`, but is there a simple way to do this at the web console level?

Answer (score 2):

In order to do that you will have to configure AWS Custom Monitoring scripts to forward custom metrics to your AWS Cloudwatch. Then you can watch custom metrics link Disk Usage , Memory, etc on Cloudwatch.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/mon-scripts.html

Comment: custom cloudwatch is the way to do the job.